# Hitting Time of a continuous time finite state Markov process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose $X_t$ is a continuous time, time homogeneous, ergodic Markov chain taking values in the state space $\{x,y\}$.  Suppose $X_t$ is characterized by the forward equation
$$
\frac{dp_t}{dt}=Ap_t
,
$$
where $p_t$ is the transition probability of $X_t$ at time $t$.

1. Is there a closed-form solution for the first passage (hitting) time
   to go from state $x$ to state $y$?  I've seen a few solutions to
   this problem in discrete time but I wasn't sure how to translate
   them to continuous time.
2. More interestingly, if $q \in [0,1]$ then how can I calculate the hitting time
   $$
   \inf
   \left\{\Delta \geq 0 :
   \mathbb{P}\left(
   \cup_{\delta \in [0,\Delta]}
   \{
     X_t=X_{t+\delta}
   \}
   |X_t
   \right)\geq q
   \right\}?
   $$

Comment: Your expression for the forward equation is wrong - it certainly shouldn't have $X_t$ in it!

Comment: The hitting time is a random variable. Are you looking for the expected hitting time?  Or the distribution of hitting time?  Note also that your inf expression is likely not what you really want.  For a continuous time Markov chain, given that $X_t=k$, the extra time we wait to transition out of state $k$ is exponentially distributed with some rate $v_k$, and so the probability of transitioning exactly at time $t$ is zero.  So for any constant $\Delta \geq 0$ we have $$P[\cup_{\delta \in [0, \Delta]} \{X_t = X_{t+\delta}\}|X_t=k] = 1$$ So a better hitting time definition is needed.